# how to add multiple boxplots to same axis set

Tags: r, lattice, bwplot

I'm trying to plot 4 groups of data as boxplots on the same set of axis.
I've been able to use the `print()` function to plot them on separate plots, but can't figure out how to plot them all together, preferably using the base package or lattice

below is some code I am trying, but it keeps coming up with error:

```
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Heres the code I'm currently trying:

```
Summer <- SeasonalMax$Summer
Autumn <- SeasonalMax$Autumn
Winter <- SeasonalMax$Winter
Spring <- SeasonalMax$Spring

boxplot(Summer, Autumn, Winter, Spring,
    main = "Multiple boxplots for comparision",
    at = c(1,2,3,4),
    names = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"),
    las = 2,
    col = c("red","orange", "blue", "pink"))
```

Comment: Your code works for me as expected: https://imgur.com/nArWQIi . Maybe I am misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

First melt the data into long format

```
# Dummy dataset
Dat <- data.frame(Spring = runif(10,0,1),
           Summer = runif(10,0,1),
           Autumn = runif(10,0,1),
           Winter = runif(10,0,1))
```

Then melt the data into long format with either : reshape2 package

```
library(reshape2)
melt(Dat)
```

or tidyr package

```
library(tidyr)
gather(Dat,key="Season",value="Value")
```

Then when you plot the boxplot , use the formula argument as follows
[I will continue with tidyr because I named the columns]

```
Dat2 <- gather(Dat,key="Season",value="Value")
with(Dat2,boxplot(Value~Season))
```

And with all your additions

```
with(Dat2,boxplot(Value~Season,
     main = "Multiple boxplots for comparision",
     at = c(1,2,4,5),
     names = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"),
     las = 2,
     col = c("red","orange", "blue", "pink")))
```

Comment: when I use the gather() function I get the message 'Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped' ... and then if I ignore it my output boxplots are incorrect, any idea as to why?

Comment: Does this occur when you use the sample data.frame I suggested in this answer, or is this using your own data? If it is your own data, please post a sample of it. It is most likely due additional variables in the data frame. If there is another variable you dont want to include in the gather process then do the following: `gather(Dat,key="Season",value="Value",-unwantedVariable1, -unwantedvariable2)`. You can add as many `-variable` parameters as you require

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot2` and `data.table`, I think it is easier, here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.table(Spring = c(runif(9,0,1),2),
                  Summer = runif(10,0,1),
                  Autumn = runif(10,0,1),
                  Winter = runif(10,0,1))
dat1 = melt(dat)

ggplot(data=dat1,aes(x=variable,y=value)) +geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red")
ggplot(data=dat1,aes(x=variable,y=value,colour=variable)) +geom_boxplot()
```

[boxplot by group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZyOv.png)